# Invalid template file: 'post/head.phtml' in module: 'Carpetcall_Blogs' block's name: 'mpblog.post.head'

Tags: magento2

I need to override the following file function in my custom module

File - Mageplaza\Blog\Block\Post\View
Function Name - getBlogTitle()

As I need to remove '- Blog | Ideas & Advice | Carpet Call' from the meta title

- When I override using preference method, I am getting following error

> ```
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'post/head.phtml' in module: 'Carpetcall_Blogs'
> ```
>
> block's name: 'mpblog.post.head'

Please advice. Following is the new file changes, I made

```
<?php

namespace Carpetcall\Blogs\Block\Post;

class View extends \Mageplaza\Blog\Block\Post\View
{
    public function getBlogTitle($meta = false)
    {
        $blogTitle = parent::getBlogTitle($meta);

        $post = $this->getBlogObject();
        if (!$post) {
            return $blogTitle;
        }

        if ($meta) {
            if ($post->getMetaTitle()) {
                $blogTitle[] = $post->getMetaTitle();
            } else {
                $blogTitle[] = ucfirst($post->getName());
            }

            return $blogTitle;
        }

        return ucfirst($post->getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want to remove exactly? Can you please share screen shot?

Comment: Have you checked added answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **setModuleName** while overriding file. With the use of below code your error "invalid template file" will be resolved. Please add like below:-

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Mageplaza\Blog\Block\Post\View'));
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

In your post i can assume that you are trying to remove "- Blog" from your Meta title and you want to set just post name. Then let me tell you that if you want to change only for post view page then you can implement it by below code. You don't need to override getBlogTitle() function

Updated whole code:-

```
<?php

namespace Carpetcall\Blogs\Block\Post;

class View extends \Mageplaza\Blog\Block\Post\View
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Mageplaza\Blog\Block\Post\View'));
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
    
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set($this->getPost()->getName());
    }
}
```

Like above code you can remove "- Blog".

Above code is practically tested. Please check and let me know.